# SQL database command not updating

Tags: mysql

I am trying to execute this:

```
UPDATE WORKS_ON
SET Hours = 5.0
WHERE Essn=99988777 AND Pno=10;
```

and it threw an error,

```
19:07:29    UPDATE WORKS_ON SET Hours=5.0 WHERE Essn=99988777 AND Pno=10    Error Code: 1175. You are using safe update mode and you tried to update a table without a WHERE that uses a KEY column To disable safe mode, toggle the option in Preferences -> SQL Queries and reconnect.    0.000 sec
```

I did what it asks and reconnected, now there is no error but doesn't do anything

```
19:36:26    UPDATE WORKS_ON SET Hours= 5.0 WHERE Essn=99988777 AND Pno=10   0 row(s) affected Rows matched: 0  Changed: 0  Warnings: 0  0.000 sec
```

I want all `Hours` for people that have `Essn=999887777` and `Pno=10`. Hours will change to 5.0

Comment: Please provide sample data, expected results, and learn how to format your posts.

Comment: Just add in the WHERE clause a KEY-value that matches everything like a primary-key

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hope you have already unchecked safe updates in preferences.
From what you have posted it looks like there are no matching rows where Essn=99988777 and Pnp=10 at the same time.If you can provide sample data and expected results it would be better

Answer (score 0):

First set `SQL_SAFE_UPDATES=0`, It’s because you try to update a table without a `WHERE` that uses a `KEY` column, if you use `PRIMARY KEY` then it would not create that kind of problem, let's try this way

```
SET SQL_SAFE_UPDATES=0;
UPDATE WORKS_ON
SET Hours = 5.0
WHERE Essn=99988777 AND Pno=10;
```

**EDIT**
you can modify your query to follow the rule (use `PRIMARY KEY` on `WHERE` clause), if it doesn't work, then precede the (`table name` with the `schema name`) like

```
UPDATE your_schemaname.WORKS_ON
SET Hours = 5.0
WHERE Essn=99988777 AND Pno=10;
```

Comment: i found one issue, Essn was supposed to be, Essn='99988777' so this got rid of the error. but when i execute the command nothing happens